# extract money value from euro sign using regex in r

Tags: extract

i have a column which gives the average daily rate of a room in euros.
FYI: When I upload the csv into R the euro sign turns into \u0080

Question: how do i apply regex to extract the numeric value for the entire column. My column is called: train$average_daily_rate

This is what it looks like:

"99  \u0080"
"113.53  \u0080"
"81.82  \u0080"

I want my ouput to be:
99
113.82
81.82

I have no idea
I thought something like this... "(\d+.\d)\s\s[0-9a-fxA-FX]+"

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this expression to each value: ^.+?(?= \u0080|$), where ?= is a positive lookahead, " \u0080" is what you don't want to capture (escaped so that's why you have the double ) and | makes sure that the sequence is at the end of the string.

PS: Make sure to use meaningful tags for future questions, in this case for example #r and/or #regex instead of "extract"

Comment: So when i put your regex solution in regex101.com it works.. but when i put it in the regexec() function i get an error: "regcomp error: 'Invalid regexp'"

This is what i tried: 
regex_avg_daily_rate <- regexec("^.+?(?= \\u0080|$)", train$average_daily_rate)